# Swap elements in char array

Tags: c, arrays, udp

This seems like it should be pretty simple to do but I'm struggling with this question. I'm trying to swap 2 elements of a char array (prefer not to use pointers) in a very specific way. I have an array called buffer that has a text string in it. If the index is odd, then that element needs to be swapped with it's "mirror counterpart" (i.e., if the index is buffer[5], then it needs to be swapped with the 5th element from the end of the array. I have the pseudo-code for it but I can't implement it. Here is my crack at it (it's probably terrible code, mind you):

```
    while(i<strlen(buffer)/2){
        if(i%2 ==1){
            temp = buffer[i];
            buffer[i] = buffer[strlen(buffer)-i-1];
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-i-1] = temp;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Here's the pseudo-code for further clarification:

```
for each char resp[x] in the sending buffer resp
    if the index of resp[x] is odd // resp[0] is the first element, hence its index is 1 (i.e., odd) 
        switch the value of resp[x] and resp[len(resp)-x-1];
    endif
end for
```

**EDIT**

The question that I have is, how do I swap elements of an array? Trying this method doesn't quite clean up my array like I'd want...This is a decryption algorithm and I'm trying to use it to straighten out the encrypted text that's in `buffer[]`

**EDIT2**

Here's a screenshot of what I'm getting...The first set of legible text is what is the original text in the array, the second is the jumbled up array, and the last chunk of text is what should be the "Cleaned Up" version to look like the original text w/ a time stamp.

[image]

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: It looks like it should work to me. What's the problem? All the repeated calls to `strlen()` are a bad idea, but other than that it seems fine.

Comment: @Barmar My text is still jumbled and illegible. I could assign a variable to hold the length of the text string just so it looks nicer though

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't quite clean up my array like I'd want"? Please show some sample input, the expected result, and the result you're getting instead.

Comment: @Barmar just uploaded an edit with a screen shot

Comment: I don't see how your swapping routine could possibly turn the jumbled text back into the original text. The jumbled text isn't just swapped characters, so swapping them back doesn't return the original.

Comment: It works here: http://ideone.com/cNM7SL

Comment: @Travis, The sample input and output in your screenshot do not appear to correspond to each other under the scrambling algorithm you described.  It looks like at least part of that may be that you are truncating one or both ends when you print it.  Possibly the whole issue revolves around an off-by-one error, as I observe that the characters that are left in place between scrambled text and your final output are exactly the ones that should be moved.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that my index check was off by 1, rather than do `while(i%2 == 1)`, it should be `while(i%2 == 0)`. Here's the prompt that was given to me:
"The encryption algorithm implemented at the server is simple: for each character at the odd index of the sending buffer, switch it with its “mirror counterpart” (i.e., the character at the same index if we count from the end of the buffer). For the characters at even indexes, we don’t touch them. The pseudocode is as follows:

    `/* pseudocode from above comments */`

Answer (score 1):

Just rotate each position into a holding space while it is in turn populated with its opposite, then populate the opposite with the value in the holding space.  This is essentially what you are doing.

Here is a variation that might be easier to read:

```
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[] = {"this is a string of characters"};
    char character=0;  //holding space for jumping characters
    int i,len,halfLen;

    len = strlen(buffer);//do this only once
    halfLen = len/2;

    //reverse the characters in string
    for(i=0;i<halfLen;i++)
    {
        character = buffer[i];
        buffer[i] = buffer[len-1 - i];
        buffer[len-1 - i] = character;
    }
    printf(buffer);

    getchar();

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This is close, I'm getting the last ~25% of the message in order correctly including the time stamp, but the rest is still jumbled with line breaks.

Comment: @TravisPatterson - I cannot tell from your post, can you tell me how `buffer` is declared and defined?  i.e. is it created with enough space to contain the string it is holding?   _Two things to consider_, ***1)*** a C string is defined as an array of characters terminated by a `\0` (NULL) character. There needs to be enough space to contain the string as well as the NULL terminator.   ***2)***  It is possible to write more data to a buffer than the buffer owns space for. This would invoke undefined behavior. Have you met both of these criteria with the particular string you are failing with?

Comment: The problem has been solved (as can be seen below), the reason why I only had a fragment of my message correctly ordered was due to placement of a parenthesis in the middle of the swapping.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it...turns out it was a stupid typo on my part.

```
while(i<strlen(buffer)/2){
    if(i%2 == 0){
        temp = buffer[i];
        buffer[i] = buffer[strlen(buffer)-i-1];
        buffer[strlen(buffer)-i-1] = temp;
    }
    i++;
}
```

is what I should have. My error came from the conditional statement of the `if` block should be `if(i%2 == 0)` rather than 'if(i%2 == 1)' then I had a typo in this line:

```
buffer[i] = buffer[strlen(buffer)-i-1];
```

I had misplaced the closing parenthesis of the `strlen()` call, somehow it got moved out to between the 1 and ]. I also had to swap the `i` and the `1` of that same line on the right side.

Comment: _misplaced the closing parenthesis_...    Well that would do it :)  (saw this after I left the comment above.  Will leave the comment just in case it is useful to anyone else)

Comment: Haha, and I just replied to your comment before seeing this comment here.